# how to solve the connection problem with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server 2016 Database using **pyodbc** with django.

In the SQL configuration manager i have all the network configurations as **Enabled**

- shared memory
- Named Pipes
- TCP/IP

**FireWall is turned OFF**

I tried using **localhost**  and it worked fine but when I tried to connect to a server on the same network it did not work and displayed the below error:

> OperationalError at /connect/
>
> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL
> Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
> connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001]
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0);
> [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or
> instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
> to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
> instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
> remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
> (53)')

I tried to check the ODBC Driver on the server and it displays these drivers:

- ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
- SQL Server
- SQL Server Native Client 11.0

and I tried both of them but no success.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pyodbc
# from .models import Artist
# Create your views here.

def connect(request):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=AB-INT-SQL;'
                      'Database=testDB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    c = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Artist')

    return render (request,'connect.html',{"c":c})
```

**connect.html**

```
{% for row in c %}
    {{ row }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you running multiple SQL instances on the same server?

Comment: @ShekarKola no its one machine name with the default instance but several databases. but i am specified the required database

Answer (score 1):

If there is only 1 SQL instance installed on the server, just do quick check with `telnet HOSTNAME 1433` to confirm SQL Server accepting the communication on default port number.

if `telnet` doesn't work, add new rule in fire-wall (via Firewall advanced settings) with port numbers `1433 and 1434` even though have turn-off the firewall. Still doesn't work, restart SQL Service and then have a look at SQL error log for a message (following message must appear after restart time)

> Server is listening on [ 'any' ipv4 1433].

Aside from this (once telnet test works), i believe, you need use the `driver` in connection string as `"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"` which you may have already tried.

Edit: SQL Error log screenshot

[image]

Comment: i followed your answer and it somehow made me on the right track  but now it display another error : `('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452)')`  

yet  its  windows  and SQL  authentication mode.

Comment: @DevDj, good to hear that, if you don't have any concern to avoid `windows authentication`, use `SQL authentication` which required you to adjust the connection string accordingly. I believe, by doing this `Trusted_Connection=no;` would allow you to use SQL authentication which lead us to add `UID` and `PWD` manually in connection string.

Comment: Yes, SQL server side it has to be `Mixed mode`, but you need change the connection string parameters as mentioned in my last comment.  
 `Trusted_Connection=no` and add user name password

Comment: @ Shekar Kola i did as u suggest in your  comment and add the UID and PWD BUT  it display  `login failed  for user 'test' `... yet i am able to create a connection on the SSMS

Comment: Can you just open SQL Error log, and see the reason for `failed login`. added screenshot for your reference: