# Trying to connect to SQL Server Express from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sql-server-express

I have installed SQL Server Express and have configured such that TCP/IP, Named Pipes, and Shared Memory are all enabled. I have also enabled the "sa" user account and set the password to "password". I can login/connect to the SQL Server just fine if I use SMSS. However, when I try to connect via my code, it keeps telling me that my login has failed.

```
"databaseConfig": {
        "user": "sa",
        "password": "password",
        "server": "localhost",
        "database": "Test",
        "port": 1433
    }

const connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(databaseConfig);
    return connection.connect().then((pool) => {
        let request = pool.request();
        request = request.input('username', sql.VarChar, username);
        ...
    });
```

So, whenever I try to connect using something similar to what I posted above, I get the following error. Really not sure what's wrong here as I believe I setup everything correctly.

```
(node:12228) [DEP0064] DeprecationWarning: tls.createSecurePair() is deprecated. Please use tls.TLSSocket instead.
(node:12228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.processLogin7Response (node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1142:16)
    at Connection.message (node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1624:21)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:857:45)
    at MessageIO.<anonymous> (node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:751:18)
    at MessageIO.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ReadablePacketStream.<anonymous> (node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:102:16)
    at ReadablePacketStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
(node:12228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12228) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: are you sure you don't have multi mysql versions installed on your system ?

Comment: yes because I just uninstalled and reinstalled sql express

Comment: Are you sure that both Windows and username/password logins are enabled?

Comment: Yup I have it set so SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode are both enabled.

Comment: Using SSMS look in the SQL Server logs for additional information about the failed logins.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you might have tried `localhost\SQLExpress` when you connect via SSMS which managed by `SQL Browser` service to re-direct the connection to particular named instance.

To establish named instance connection without specifying it's name, configure static port ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxnUu.jpg)), and use always that port number in connection string.

*Note: Same port cannot be used again if you planning to install second instance of SQL Express within same server*

[Further troubleshooting steps..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554420/6598234) or [DBA.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57448109/6598234)